# Needs to restart nextjs app every time i upload file using fs on vps with pm2 and nginx

Tags: nginx, next.js, deployment, vps, pm2

If i upload the file and try to visit it by link, it throws 404 error, if i restart pm2, the issue gets fixed. App is built on nextjs and deployed on vps using nginx and pm2. Here is my pm2 configuration

```
module.exports = {
  apps: [
    {
      name: "consumerapp",
      script: "npm",
      args: "start",
      autorestart: true,
      watch: false,
      exec_mode: "cluster",
      instances: 4,
      ignore_watch: ["node_modules"],
      max_memory_restart: "1G",
      env: {
        NODE_ENV: "production",
      },
    },
  ],
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you change:

```
watch: false,
```

to

```
watch: true,
```

PM2 will reload your app everytime a file is changed in you application tree.

Not chure that it's what you want to achieve?